# F test or T test for a regression model

Tags: regression, self-study, t-test, f-test

I am reviewing some lecture material and I was wondering if there was a typo in the material. I believe the material is trying to show the effect of multicollinearity on the independent variables in a regression model, see the image below.

I believe the regression was performed in SAS and having checked a sample output from that tool it should be a t test and not an f test as shown. Am i correct?

A t test will tell you if a statistic (in this case the coefficient for exercise etc) are statistically significant whereas an F test is what an Anova will dump out to tell you if a group of statistics are significant?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that an [*F* distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution) with (1,*n*) degrees of freedom is the square of a *t* distribution with *n* degrees of freedom. Looks like the *F* values above are the squares of what the *t* values (estimate/std.error) would have been. Just like ANOVA (using the *F*-test) with 2 groups gives the same result as a *t*-test, you get the same probabilities in the end.

Comment: Thanks EdM for your reply. To be honest I'm still trying to piece all these tests together and what they actually mean. Am I right in saying that if I have a very high Rsquared value this indicates that my independent variables have minimised the SSE very well? From the very small F values I can deduce that my results are significant and that I can reject H0 such that the slope of the line does not equal 0? But since this is an example of multicollinearity, this is what should happen by overfitting? Given that Y is optimism, sleep and exercise shouldn't have a neg impact on it?

Comment: You haven't presented enough information to gauge whether you have multicollinearity or overfitting. As you recognize, you could have a high $R^2$ and a "significant" fit with overfitting, so that the same model works very poorly at predicting new cases. If this is a multiple regression model then you have to be careful interpreting individual coefficients as they are determined by "accounting for" all the other variables. This might lead to counter-intuitive signs for coefficients particularly if the real relations to outcome aren't strictly linear.